# cross apply behaves weird when used with group by

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, cross-apply, lateral-join

I don't understand why the columns `correct` and `incorrect` have different values in this case. To be honest - it seems weird this is valid SQL, because the `cross apply` part is not an aggregation function computed because of the `group by`.

```
with Foo as (
    select 1 as id, 'foo_1' as txt from Dual union all
    select 2, 'foo_2' from Dual),
Bar as (
    select 1 as id, 'bar_1' as txt, 1 as foo_id from Dual union all
    select 2, 'bar_2', 1 from Dual union all
    select 3, 'bar_3', 1 from Dual union all
    select 4, 'bar_4', 2 from Dual)
select 
    f.id,
    listagg(b.txt, ', ') within group (order by b.id) as correct,
    incorrect
from Foo f
join Bar b on f.id = b.foo_id
cross apply (
    select 
        listagg(txt, ', ') within group (order by id) as incorrect
    from Bar 
    where foo_id = f.id)
group by f.id
order by f.id;
```

The result is:

```
ID  CORRECT                 INCORRECT
1   bar_1, bar_2, bar_3     bar_4
2   bar_4                   bar_4
```

But when I do remove the `group by` part, and add the `distinct` like the following:

```
with Foo as (
    select 1 as id, 'foo_1' as txt from Dual union all
    select 2, 'foo_2' from Dual),
Bar as (
    select 1 as id, 'bar_1' as txt, 1 as foo_id from Dual union all
    select 2, 'bar_2', 1 from Dual union all
    select 3, 'bar_3', 1 from Dual union all
    select 4, 'bar_4', 2 from Dual)
select distinct
    f.id,
    incorrect_now_correct
from Foo f
join Bar b on f.id = b.foo_id
cross apply (
    select 
        listagg(txt, ', ') within group (order by id) as incorrect_now_correct
    from Bar 
    where foo_id = f.id)
order by f.id;
```

I do get the following result:

```
ID  INCORRECT_NOW_CORRECT
1   bar_1, bar_2, bar_3
2   bar_4
```

Which is the result I expected from the `incorrect` column in the first query.

Is the `group by` clause treated differently when using the `group by` clause? Until now I only thought it's something more of a intelligent join with a subquery. Adding `incorrect` to the `group by` part makes it work like it should, without it the behavior is like described in the result of the first query. It compiles, runs and returns a value which is somewhat random.

Edit: The DB version is **Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition 12.1.0.2.0**

Comment: This works when I try it out:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a35ddb2bf5c15108146245cd27bb84be.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Could it be an issue with Oracle 12c?

Comment: It could be.  But there is already one typo in your query (leaving out `incorrect` in the `group by`).  I would recommend that you qualify *all* column references to be sure there are no other typos.

Comment: It's not a typo, it's an actual Query, which I'm able to run using SQL developer. I ran a similar analytic query on production data and now I'm confused why it did compile and was executed.